# phpize Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php

Tags: php, centos7

I am getting trouble with `phpize Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php` when try to install any package with pecl.

Server:Centos 7
Php Version:7.0.14

I installed also php-devel.When search the php-devel with `yum search php-devel` terminal shows as below:

```
php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php54-php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php55-php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php56-php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php70-php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php71-php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
```

So how can I achive this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you sort out this issue? I am also facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to install php71w-devel for php 7.1

Comment: Please See this first: [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) and [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)